# I installed NetBeans 12.4. I have JDK 16.0.2. But after the installation of netbeans, it doesn't start. I found this file in nb folder hs_err_pid10436

Tags: java-16, netbeans-12

The file contains the following text. This is just some of it.

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffdef143760, pid=10436, tid=15852
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (16.0.2+7) (build 16.0.2+7-67)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007ffdef143760
[error occurred during error reporting (printing problematic frame), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffdef143f10]
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```